# mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, drivers, sd-card

I have an issue with my Arch.I insert the SD I can't detect it.

Also I find the following error kernel log:

```
  uname -a 
    Linux localhost.localdomain 4.9.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 26 09:22:26 CET 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
    dmesg
    [    3.663535] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
    [    4.515911] random: fast init done
    [    4.720224] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

---

```
lspci -v 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Memory at f1220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at f124a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at f124b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Memory at f1248000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at f124e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 3080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3088 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3060 [size=32]
    Memory at f124c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d12 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f1100000-f11fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f1000000-f10fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at f1244000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pmc_core

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 129
    Memory at f1240000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at f1230000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at f124d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-V (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at f1200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 4210
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at f1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5048
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Memory at f1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

So I can fix this?

Comment: It's `Connection timed out` error. What hardware do you use? Do other cards work well? Dos this card work well in other readers?

Comment: The same card worked via usb adapter.
And the laptop integrated card reader is able to read other cards.

Comment: I am also getting this issue with new 128GB Class V30 Lexar and Sandisk SD cards.

Seems to be unsupported class version issue.

Answer (score 1):

Error -110 means timeout. Basically, your MMC controller is not able to talk correctly with your SD card. It usually happens when your card is not correctly inserted in the slot (for example the spring is pushing back your card too far) or maybe you are using a micro SD card and it is not correctly inserted in the SD card adapter. What can also happen is that your SD card adapter is slightly broken and some connections are not correctly made (e.g. your card has negotiated 4 bits mode and some lines are in fact not connected).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problems with my Realtek reader. If necessary I can fill in the details (reader and card types, kernel and driver version, results of attempts to solve this).

In the end it boils down to some SD cards just not being supported by the current Realtek driver, and so far no prospect of this being solved. These cards seem to be very rare; I purchased another one as replacement and it worked, like all others I could lay my hands on. It doesn't seem to depend on the speed class, capacity, or anything else that's obvious. The same card is working with other readers (USB), and in my camera, for years without issues.

I'm not able to name any official source, however. Most of this has been established by the company that provided the Ubuntu distribution together with my notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue on Fedora, I've installed a few updates (including a new kernel) and didn't restart the system. After reboot everything works fine.

I hope it will help someone.